# delete the item on search box if clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am trying to built a `dropdown` menu with a text box.When the text box is clicked the items appear and when the items are clicked they turn green(selected) and show up in the text box.
I was wondering if there was a way in which i could just click the item on the search box and the item gets unselected (ungreen). How can i capture the click on the element name in the text box.!

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Are you trying to click some text in textbox and unselect value related to that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is exactly what you are looking for but it may help you to achieve whatever you are trying to do

```
<select multiple>
<option class="anOption">One</option>
<option class="anOption">Two</option>
<option class="anOption">Three</option>
<option class="anOption">Four</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var options = document.getElementsByClassName("anOption");
for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++){
options[i].addEventListener('click', function (){
this.style.backgroundColor="green";
});
}
```